# Assigned a new Role in EC2 with S3FullAccess policy, but unable to upload a file from front end React app

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, identity-management

I want to have controlled access to the S3 bucket to upload a file. Created an EC2 instance and attached a new S3FullAccess policy. Now from the front end (React App), I'm trying to upload a file to this S3 bucket, but the upload process is not getting initiated.

when I tried with active and security keys in Env file, the upload works, but I don't want to use keys because of known problems. Instead, my idea was to create a new IAM Role and assign a S3FullAccess policy, then map this to a EC2 instance where we have our React application.  Then when I tried to upload a file from the React App, the upload is not getting initiated.

Comment: When you say from the React App you mean from the browser?

Comment: What code is actually running on the EC2 instance? Do you have a server component (e.g. built with Express or Flask) that your front-end clients make HTTP API requests to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using React and you've stated that it will be running from the client devices, then IAM roles might not help here.
What you can do is to implement S3 pre-signed URLs which will be sent to the client to enable him to upload to S3.
This need to be implemented in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are referring from within React codebase ya?
The approach is simple. Attach S3FullAccess role to your EC2 Instance.
From React application code initiate aws sdk without keys and you are done. The sdk will automatically know the EC2 IAM role attached and will direct you to AWS S3 without having to explicitly specify the key within the codebase.

Comment: React is typically (always?) a client-side UI framework. It's not typically running on EC2. It's running in the client's browser or in a mobile app (if React Native).